# Why Task.Factory.StartNew returns immediately while Task.Run does not?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Consider this code snippet:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i) {
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i)
    await tasks[i];

Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

This works as expected, taking 4.000 ms to execute. However, if I exchange `Task.Run` with `Task.Factory.StartNew` it takes only 0.006 ms !

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself after reading this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/

> By using the async keyword here, the compiler is going to map this
>   delegate to be a `Func<Task<int>>`: invoking the delegate will return
>   the `Task<int>` to represent the eventual completion of this call.  And
>   since the delegate is `Func<Task<int>>`, `TResult` is `Task<int>`, and thus
>   the type of ‘t’ is going to be `Task<Task<int>>`, not `Task<int>`.

So this code works as expected:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i) {
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i)
    await await (tasks[i] as Task<Task>);

Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Which can be implemented also using `Unwrap`:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i) {
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        await Task.Delay(4000);
    }).Unwrap();
}
for (var i = 0; i < tasks.Length; ++i)
    await tasks[i];

Console.WriteLine("Done!");
```

Answer (score 10):

> Can anyone explain why?

Put simply, `StartNew` does not understand `async` delegates.

So, [when your delegate returns an incomplete task at its first `await`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), `StartNew` sees the delegate exit and considers its work complete. This is why it returns a `Task<Task>` here. `Task.Run` has special logic to handle asynchronous delegates, automatically unwrapping the inner task.

This is only one of the pitfalls of using `StartNew` with asynchronous code; I cover this and the others in detail in my blog post [`StartNew` is Dangerous](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439(v=vs.110).aspx)

> there is a difference in behavior between the two methods regarding :
>   Task.Run(Action) by default does not allow child tasks started with
>   the TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent option to attach to the
>   current Task instance, whereas StartNew(Action) does

So, the `Task.Run` will wait while execution will finish and the `Task.Factory.StartNew` return a task immediately.